# Systemd Networkd [Match] Rule Multiple Matches

Tags: networking, systemd

If I have a static network configuration like this:

```
[Match]
Driver=mlx4_en

[Network]
Address=10.1.0.10/24
Gateway=10.1.0.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

and say I have a dual port NIC which uses the driver `mlx4_en` then I have obviously two matches. What is systemd network doing with the [Network] definition then? Obviously it is a bad idea to give both interfaces the same IP.

Comment: I'm looking at the same issue with `DHCP=yes` where it would make sense to configure both interfaces (with some priority handling) but it seems to just pick one of them.

Answer (score 0):

try matching with MACAddress then you will have two IP https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. When the link breaks, your answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question. Please include at least a summary so the answer can stand on its own. Thank you!